# Items disappears while scrolling Gridview very fast. Also the image dimension changes while scrolling fastly

Tags: android

**Items disappears while scrolling Gridview very fast. Also the image dimension changes while scrolling fastly.**
**Here is my code :**

```
 public View getView(final int position, View gridView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (gridView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                gridView = new View(context);
                gridView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.view_initial_gallery, null);
                holder.dirname = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.fname);
                holder.dirimg = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.folder);
                holder.tick = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.tick);

                File file=folders.get(position).getFilelist().get(0);
                holder.dirname.setText(folders.get(position).getFoldername());
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(new File(file.getPath()))
                        .resize(300, 300)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .into(holder.dirimg);

                gridView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder)gridView.getTag();
            }
            return gridView;
        }
```

Comment: in your xml's Gridview. give android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't help. I think there is some problem with the creation of views but i am not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue with notifyDataSetChanged(). Hope it will work for you also.

```
mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
   //     Boolean isScrollStop=false;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount){

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, except that I used Glide instead of Picasso for image loading. I'm guessing your ImageView's dimensions are set to `wrap_content`. Try setting height and width to explicit values in dp's, it worked for me.

Comment: It is more helpful to include code snippet demonstrating exactly what you are suggesting here - but even more helpful is to explain why this should work.